# Display text inside the span if the span is empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would like to add some text inside a span if it is empty.

The span below DOES contain text, so it should do nothing.

```
<span class="content">This span has text so do nothing</span>
```

The span below does not contain any text, so I want the Javascript to automatically add text into the span for me, I want it display "Public".

```
<span class="content"></span>
```

So the final result for the above example will be

```
<span class="content">Public</span>
```

Comment: where is your JS? what have you tried?

Comment: Also what will trigger this insertion? Page load?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the [:empty](https://api.jquery.com/empty-selector/) selector

For example

```
$("span.content:empty")
  .text("Public")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use **[`html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/)** or **[`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/)** with callback function

```js
$('span.content').html(function(i, v) {
  return v.trim() == '' ? 'public' : v;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="content">This span has text so do nothing</span>
<span class="content"></span>
```

Answer (score 1):

in jQuery

```
$span = $(".span");
if($span.text() == ""){
    $span.text("Public");
}
```

Here you can see Example - JSFIDDLE - http://jsfiddle.net/3vcL2e97/

Comment: Hey this is great. It works but what would the code be if I had multiple spans on the same page? e.g.

<span>Hello</span>
<span></span>
<span></span>
<span>Hello</span> 

So the two spans that don't have content would show "Public" ?

Comment: if you want add this condition on multiple span then you need to use each function to loop all spans ...
here is example how to do 
http://jsfiddle.net/5gqcm8oz/

Comment: or you empty selector ...
$("span:empty").text("Public");
http://jsfiddle.net/5gqcm8oz/2/

Answer (score 0):

Using Pure JavaScript:

```
   function myFunction() { 

    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("content"); 
    for(i=0;i<x.length;i++)
    {
if(x[i].innerHTML=="")
    {
    x[i].innerHTML = "Public"; 
    }
    }

}
```

Here is the fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/7fet87rb/